# How to find cardinality of all columns in kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to find number of distinct values in all columns for some query. I found that [dcount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dcount-aggfunction) works well but you have to supply the specific column. I want to do this on all columns, where the column names and the number of columns are dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to explicitly include all columns of interest.

note that any additional column you add to the query will increase the resources utilization of the query, so if you have any knowledge about columns that are likely to be of high cardinality, consider including only those.

FWIW: you can generate the query (for all columns, with the caveat above) dynamically, then invoke *the result* of this:

```
let tableName = "my_table";
let datetime_column_name = "my_datetime_column";
let lookback_period = 1h;
let column_names = toscalar(
    table(tableName)
    | getschema 
    | summarize make_set(ColumnName)
);
print query = strcat(
    tableName,
    "\n| where ",
    datetime_column_name,
    " > ago(timespan(",
    lookback_period,
    "))\n| summarize dcount(",
    strcat_array(column_names, "),\ndcount("),
    ")")
```

Comment: awesome idea! worked great for me, thanks